# mongodb aggregate to get recursively every parent of category by parent id

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup, graphlookup

I tried to do it with graphLookup, but ended up with no result. Is it possible to do it with lookup only or I need to add more aggregation functions? My collection and expected result below

My collection:

```
[
{
    "_id": "62acec38aa7bfb93f882c7d5",
    "attribute_ids": [
        "62acff98aa7bfb93f882c7f2",
        "62acff15c51e86326c759dae"
    ],
    "parent_id": null,
    "name": "category1"
},
{
    "_id": "62acec38aa7bfb93f882c7d4",
    "attribute_ids": [
        "62a0cfb6ba45413ec2aea923"
    ],
    "parent_id": "62acec38aa7bfb93f882c7d5",
    "name": "category2"
},
{
    "_id": "62adcdbaaa7bfb93f882c7f8",
    "attribute_ids": [
        "62acff98aa7bfb93f882c7f2",
        "62acff15c51e86326c759dae"
    ],
    "parent_id": "62acec38aa7bfb93f882c7d4",
    "name": "category2"
}
]
```

As a result I want to have this:

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the result that I ended up with https://mongoplayground.net/p/_d0WNOS71bx

Comment: @Tx_monster it is answer with example